# Configurable product validation doesn't work correct

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, form-validation, magento2.3.2

When I click add cart it show second option. I think it should show first option.

Now it show: 
[image: Now it show:]
I think it should show like this
[image: I think it should show]
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click add cart it will show second option.
It works by default of magento.

Comment: Yes, it's default of magento. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: What is the difference between your two screenshots?  I saw the same 2 screenshots

Comment: It should show first option, not second option.

Comment: @DavidDuong You can choose "Edit Configurations" when edit the product on backend and tick Atrribute "size" (if you want show option for Size).

Comment: I have checked but all it tick. Please check our screen: http://prntscr.com/okc5ab
Please provide more details.

Comment: Please choose one. You can re-generate product with one attribute selected.

Comment: Where can i find this option
?